# Getting error not able to implement 'PUT' method REST http request in my REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, mongoose, postman, web-deployment

I am trying to create a REST API using mongoose methods, in that when I am trying to implement PUT model in specific article section. And when I am sending the PUT request from Postman

Then I am getting the following error in my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
    at E:\REST api\Wiki-API\app.js:83:31
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at next (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:138:14)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15    at param (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at param (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:376:14)
    at Function.process_params (E:\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:421:3)
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naG14.png)

[Screenshot of Postman interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Wq8.png)

```js
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const articleSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String
};

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

//*************** Request targeting all articles ***************
app.route("/articles")

    .get(function (req, res) {

        Article.find({}, function (err, foundArticles) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(foundArticles);
            } else {
                res.send(err);
            }
        });
    })

    .post(function (req, res) {

        const newArticle = new Article({
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content
        });

        newArticle.save(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send("Successfully added the article.");
            } else {
                res.send(err);
            }
        });
    })

    .delete(function (req, res) {
        Article.deleteMany(
            {}, function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("Successfully deleted all article.");
                } else {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            }
        )
    });

//*************** Request targeting specific articles ***************

app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")

    .get(function (req, res) {
        Article.findOne({ title: req.params.articleTitle }, function (err, foundArticle) {
            if (foundArticle) {
                res.send(foundArticle);
            } else {
                res.send("No article matching that title was found.");
            }
        });
    })

    .put(function (req, res) {
        Article.updateOne(
            { title: req.params.articleTitle },
            { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
            { overwrite: true },
            function (err, res) {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("successfully updated article!");
                }
                else {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            }
        );
    });


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

After running the code and connecting it from the database, and sending http request from the postman I just seeing this error but not able to see any changes in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the body parse in order to use the `req.body`, otherwise it will be undefined.

Add the following line

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

after `const app = express();`

Comment: It is showing another error

Comment: body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option app.js:14:17
'Server started on port 3000
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at E:\Darshan\Code Playground\Web Development Bootcamp\REST api\Wiki-API\app.js:93:25
    at E:\Darshan\Code Playground\Web Development Bootcamp\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4994:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:'

Comment: ' at E:\Darshan\Code Playground\Web Development Bootcamp\REST api\Wiki-API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4996:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... '

Comment: Check out the express bodyparser documentation https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html.